# Grabbing text between either double/single quote in Python regex

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a bunch (thousands) of old unit testing scripts written with the Selenium RC interface in JavaScript. Since we're upgrading to Selenium 3, I want to try and get rid of some of the RC methods in an automated fashion using Python scripts. I'm iterating through these scripts line by line, picking up the Selenese methods, deconstructing them then attempting to rebuild with the WebDriver interface. For example:

```
selenium.type("xpath=//*[text()='test, xpath']", "test, text");
```

Would be output as...

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='test, xpath']")).sendKeys("test, text");
```

I have a system for automatically identifying the Selenese methods, storing whitespace and separating the method from the parameters, so what I'm left with is the following string:

```
("xpath=//*[text()='test, xpath']", "test, text")
```

A problem I'm running into is, these aren't always consistent. Sometimes there are double-quotes nested in single-quotes, or vice-versa, or escaped double-quotes nested in double-quotes, etc. For example:

```
("xpath=//*[text()=\"test, xpath\"]", "test, text")
('xpath=//*[text()=\'test, xpath\']', 'test, text')
('xpath=//*[text()="test, xpath"]', 'test, text')
```

These are all valid. I want to be able to always match the arguments passed into the method, whether double-quotes are used or single-quotes, plus ignore nested quotes opposite of what's used to open the string as well as escaped quotes, then return them as lists.

```
['xpath=//*[text()="test, xpath"]', 'test, text']
```

...etc. I've attempted to use the re.findall using the following expression.

```
([\"'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

What I'm getting back is this.

```
>>> print arguments
[('"', ''), ('"', '')]
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: to match all the single/double quoted strings: `'(([^'\\]*(\\.)?)*)'|"(([^"\\]*(\\.)?)*)"`

Answer (score 0):

I would not make it this complex using lookbehind or lookahead. Rather I would build a case specific regex. In your case you have something like below

> ("param1", "param2")
>
> ('param1', 'param2')

Inside these params you may have additional escaped quotes or single quotes or what not. But if look at one thing, which is split it using `", "` or `', '`, these exact patterns will rarely occur in param1 and param2

So simplest non-regex solution would be to split based on `", "` or `', '`. But then there may be extra spaces or no spaces between, so we use a pattern

```
^\(\s*["']\s*(?<first_param>.*?)("\s*,\s*"|'\s*,\s*')(?<second_param>.*?)\s*["']\s*\)$
```

`\(\s*["']\s*` to match the first brackets and any starting quote

`(?<first_param>.*?)` to match the first parameter

`("\s*,\s*"|'\s*,\s*')` to match our split command pattern

`(?<second_param>.*?)` to match the second param

`\s*["']\s*\)$` to match the end.

This is not perfect but will work in 95%+ cases of your

[image: RegEx Test]

You can check regex fiddle on below link

https://regex101.com/r/z9PytD/1/